# Custom accessor strategy for Clojure `from-java`

Tags: java, clojure, mapping, interop, javabeans

Is there any way to customise the accessor strategy used in `clojure.java.data/from-java`? `from-java` is part of the `java.data` [function lib](https://github.com/clojure/java.data).

I recently updated a third-pary Java-library that used to follow the JavaBean `get` and `set` pattern. However, after the update they went from `getProperty()` to `property()`...

I guess this change renders the `from-java` function not suitable in this case, no surprise since the objects are no longer proper JavaBeans.

Is there any way of making `from-java` aware of this accessor-pattern, or are there any other recursive mapping-mechanisms that supports this?

Comment: As folks have noted in their answers, and as you suspected in your question, `clojure.java.data` is designed to work with JavaBeans and builds on that API under the hood -- so if Java doesn't think you have a "bean", `java.data` isn't going to be able to help you much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from-java` is a multimethod, do you can override it for any class you like. There is no mechanism for teaching it an alternate naming convention (and if there were such a mechanism, I imagine it would have trouble with "every method with any name at all represents a property"). Therefore you'll have to write [manual conversions](https://github.com/clojure/java.data/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/data.clj#L290), but at least the recursion will be handled for you.

Comment: Thanks @amalloy, you confirmed my suspicion. I was hoping I didn't have to override using multimethods since I'm dealing with a huge number of different classes. But, as you say, at least I'll have recursion handled...

Answer (score 2):

It seems you will have to extend the multimethod to support the classes yourself, however, you can probably use reflection (slow, I know) to build something very generic:

- For a given object instance, find its class, then the class' `DeclaredFields`, and from each fields get their name and type
- For the same instance, use `.getDeclaredMethod` or `.getDeclaredMethods` to find methods for the given name that take no params (use an empty array for this). Those methods should be the new "getters" and you can call these in your instance to extract the values.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I didn't have to go down reflection-lane :-) But that might be an option

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Cognitect aws-api](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api) instead :)

Comment: I definitely will @slipset :-) Background for others: I was using the java aws sdk library and it went from returning JavaBeans to not returning JavaBeans after ugrading to latest version. Cognitects lib allows me to go full clojure without interop!